# Auto-execute parenthesis creates problems with setInterval?

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval(function () {myFunction()}, 1000);
(function myFunction() {
    ...
})();
```

The parenthesis around the function make it run automatically. However, it causes problems with setting the interval for that function. Is there any way to fix this? Or, perhaps, a better way to make functions run automatically? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You've created an IIFE, and the name of the function is only accessible inside the function, to the interval call, `myFunction` is not defined.

If you want to create a function, and then run it right away **and** in an interval, you just do that

```
function myFunction() {  // make pretty function
    ...
};

setInterval(function () {
    myFunction();  // make pretty function run each second
}, 1000);

myFunction(); // make pretty function run now
```